# How to filter on the property of an object in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two data sets: categories and products. I would like to filter products based on the category they belong to.

I need to filter on the category.name because the name can we equal to product.category. I know the dot nation is not accepted as function parameter but I can not find out how to pass it on.

I have tried: category["name"] and {{category.name}} without success.

```
<b-tab v-for="category in categories" v-bind:title="category.name" :key="category.id">
<div v-for="product in filteredByCategory(category.name)" :key="product.id" class="slide">
  <b-card
    v-bind:title="product.name"
    :img-src="product.imageUrl"
    style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem;"
   >
</b-card>
```

This is the filter I use.

```
filteredByCategory(category){
      return this.products.filter(product => product.category === category.name)
    }
```

Can someone help please

Comment: This would be a lot easier with data samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass name already here:

```
filteredByCategory(category.name)
```

But then try access name property again in filter function.

```
product.category === category.name
```

Change one of those lines

1. Pass category object to - `filteredByCategory(category)`
2. Or check category instead `product.category === category`

Answer (score 2):

Dot notation actually is accepted with the ES6

`function({ propHere })`

other than that I see that you already pass the category.name to the function `filteredByCategory`, but you are still using `category.name`. So it becomes like 'clothing'.name which is undefined, because string prototype doesn't have such method.